# How to completely disable selection for qtableview (for all cells)?

Tags: c++, qt, selection, qtableview, qtablewidget

I want my table to be not selectable, so that only check boxes or radio buttons could be selected, but not the cell itself. Now I have:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Solutions for QTableWidget can help too.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, I strongly recommend skimming through that whole doc page, and reading the explanatory text sections. Same for the model. It really helps if you have some idea what all is provided by the API.

Comment: You might look at `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` flag. Unset it for all items in your table model.

Comment: @hyde your linked helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
QTableView *test = new QTableView();
test->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

gives the wanted result.